# UItextFiled text on center

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have this textField

[image]

who doing text on center?///////////////////////////////////

```
 textPredmet = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 55, 200, 40)];
    textPredmet.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
    textPredmet.textColor = [UIColor blackColor]; //text color
    textPredmet.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0];  //font size

    [textPredmet drawTextInRect:CGRectMake( 30,55,200,40)];

    textPredmet.placeholder = @"Введите текст";  //place holder
    textPredmet.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; //background color
    textPredmet.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;    // no auto correction support
    textPredmet.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;  // type of the keyboard
    textPredmet.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;  // type of the return key
    textPredmet.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;  // has a clear 'x' button to the right
    textPredmet.delegate = self;    // let us be the delegate so we know when the keyboard's "Done" button is pressed
    textPredmet.background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"input.png"];
    textPredmet.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentLeft+1;
    [self.view addSubview:textPredmet];
```

Comment: What does UITextAlignmentLeft+1 actually do? You should use UITextAlignmentCenter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set below line to your code.

```
textPredmet.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
```

It will set the text center vertically.

```
  textPredmet.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
```

It will set the text center horizontally.

Also, remove below lines from your code.

```
[textPredmet drawTextInRect:CGRectMake( 30,55,200,40)];
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, UITextAlignmentLeft+1 == UITextAlignmentCenter